# R Filtering with str-detect without quotations

Tags: r, string

I want to enter a word as the x value and a dataframe in the y value. Comment_text is a in each data frame. The function will produce all rows featuring the x input.

However, the function is returning rows with the letter x. If I remove the quotations, the function does not run at all.

Any alternatives?

```
phrases <- function(x,y) {
  all <- y %>% filter(str_detect(comment_text, 'x'))
  view(all)
}
```

Comment: `y %>% filter(grepl(x, comment_text, fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: The `x` should be without quotes as it is the inputand then when you call the function, it would be `phrases('yourword',  yourdata)`.  If you quote 'x' inside, it will always be literally taken as 'x' and not the input you passed

Comment: What is the function `view`? Are you sure you don't want to `return(all)`? Or do you mean `View()` (note the capitalization) to show it in a tab in RStudio?